# Map output size for a reduce task in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

In Hadoop 0.20.2, does the jobtracker maintain any information about various map output sizes corresponding to a reduce task?

maplocations of type `Map<String, List<MapOutputLocation>>` in `ReduceCopier` contains  map output locations for the reduce task, however it doesn't seem to have any information on its sizes.